# javascript scope with underscore and object literal

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following code  and want to set all my underscore templates to use mustache syntax. If I move the _.templateSetting outside the function, it doesn't work. How would I set this globally?

thx in advance

```
arc_eh.mb={
  show_tree:function(){
    // all i want to do is move this outside and set globally 
    //  for all my underscore microtemplates
    _.templateSettings = {
      interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };

    var template=_.template("hello {{ some }}");
    var jt = { "some" : "more-something" };
    //var final=template({ some : "say-something" });
    var final=template(jt);
    console.log(final);
```

**update #1**

So I've updated your fiddle with the problem I am having here: http://jsfiddle.net/vMHeq/1/

I AGREE that you fiddle works fine - I know this is a scope issue that I'm not familiar with. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assigning to `_.templateSettings` outside the function should work assuming of course that `underscore.js` is loaded *before* you mess with `_.templateSettings`. PS: You should set all three regexes in `templateSettings` if you want to change the delimiters.

Comment: let me revisit that; that's what I tried first but being in treacherous waters, thought I'd ask. I think ur right and I made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're gonna need to set _.templateSettings options outside of your arc_eh.mb object.  If you want to use all the power of _.template you'll want to include all three settings.  I'm using {{- }}, {{= }}, and {{ }} for the formatting on this.

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{\=(.+?)\}\}/gim,
    escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim,
    evaluate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/gim
};
```

Set up a simple fiddle to show you what's up.

http://jsfiddle.net/AbLA8/1/

Comment: Thx, SAR, I have posted un updated fiddle which shows yours but with the problem I am having.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vMHeq/2/

When you have underscore templates and want to have a carrage return you have to end the line with an escape character, \.  Also you had a couple typos in the fiddle.  Check this out and see if it answers your questions.